# Heroku meteorite buildpack bug, any alternatives?

Tags: heroku, meteor, meteorite, buildpack

I've used those buildpacks for the last six months, and never had any issues:

https://github.com/oortcloud/heroku-buildpack-meteorite
https://github.com/cwaring/heroku-buildpack-meteorite-phantomjs

Now I'm getting this error when I'm trying to push my apps:

```
    You must specify a Meteor version with --release when you work with this
    project. It was created from an unreleased Meteor checkout and doesn't
    have a version associated with it.

    You can permanently set a release for this project with 'meteor update'.
tar: /app/tmp/repo.git/.cache/bundle.tar.gz: Cannot open: No such file or directory
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
tar: Child returned status 2
tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors

 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Meteor app app
```

The error occures right after Meteor and all meteroite packages have been installed.

I've posted the [issue to github](https://github.com/oortcloud/heroku-buildpack-meteorite/issues/17).

**So, can anyone recommend a working alternative to these buildpacks for temp use til this gets fixed?**

**EDIT:**

To replicate my error, do this in your terminal: `mrt create buildpack-test && cd buildpack-test/ && git init && heroku create --remote staging --stack cedar --buildpack https://github.com/oortcloud/heroku-buildpack-meteorite.git && git add -A && git commit -m 'Init' && git push staging master`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

seems like the same thing as this issue
https://github.com/oortcloud/heroku-buildpack-meteorite/issues/13

i've forked the buildpack and fixed it to meteorite version 5.1 and it seems to work just fine for me

https://github.com/nate-strauser/heroku-buildpack-meteorite

---

update: the issue has been resolved, i've switched back to the official build pack - https://github.com/oortcloud/heroku-buildpack-meteorite

Comment: Your fork works, cheers! Do you know if Tom (tmeasday) is working on a fix for the real buildpack? Kind of annoying not being able to use > 0.6 :(

Comment: no worries - i'm using my fork with a 0.6.4 meteor app - works just fine - i think they are working a fix, but since heroku is a bit of a dead end in terms of scaling, it probably wont get a lot of support

Comment: Cheers! What paas would you recommend? Haven't built any apps which requires more than one dyno yet, and nothing I've found compares to Herokus free one dyno pricing.

Comment: same here - happily using the 2x sized single dyno on heroku with mongohq - when it comes time to scale i'll probably go for aws ec2 instances or possibly modulus.io (check out demeteorizer)

Comment: cheers, was about to check them out some time ago, but never got around to it.